I'm having trouble adding the micromodal library
I am having trouble adding the micromodal library to my project.
This is the link to the library:
https://micromodal.vercel.app/#introduction
I followed all the steps in the documentation but without success.
This is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modale</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/micromodal/0.4.10/micromodal.min.js" integrity="sha512-qcwcAul7d7yUcoz3MmQABiaGDa+gVkaDWgZX6wEd/z3I6z62nQCDW3EqioQG+O+QlGCpxmJLdH5snh4IaDPiPA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="openmodal">Open</button>
    <!-- [1] -->
    <div id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">

        <!-- [2] -->
        <div tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>

            <!-- [3] -->
            <div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">


                <header>
                    <h2 id="modal-1-title">
                        Modal Title
                    </h2>

                    <!-- [4] -->
                    <button aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close>Close</button>
                </header>

                <div id="modal-1-content">
                    Modal Content
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       document.getElementById('openmodal').addEventListener('click',function(){
        MicroModal.show('modal-1'); // [1]
       }) 
    </script>
</body>

</html>

Can someone please help me?

for integrating the mircomodal of vercel app with your website , you need to change this things :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modal Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/micromodal/0.4.10/micromodal.min.js" integrity="sha512-qcwcAul7d7yUcoz3MmQABiaGDa+gVkaDWgZX6wEd/z3I6z62nQCDW3EqioQG+O+QlGCpxmJLdH5snh4IaDPiPA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <style>
        .modal {
            display: none;
        }
        .modal.is-open {
            display: block;
        }
        .modal__overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .modal__container {
            position: relative;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            max-width: 500px;
            margin: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .modal__header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .modal__close {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="openmodal">Open</button>
    <div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
            <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
                <header class="modal__header">
                    <h2 id="modal-1-title">
                        Modal Title
                    </h2>
                    <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close>&times;</button>
                </header>
                <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
                    Modal Content
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        MicroModal.init();
        document.getElementById('openmodal').addEventListener('click', function() {
            MicroModal.show('modal-1');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>



we have to just initialize the micromodal to make it so that it should interactive .
also we have to follow all these thing
modal, modal__overlay, modal__container, modal__header, modal__close, and modal__content

for onclick to open
MicroModal.show('modal-1');

link : https://codepen.io/bhautik1206/pen/XWLNoQB

Unfortunately it still doesn't work with your code. Have you tried?

did you apply css in this code ? like modal is not display ,only onclick the modal should be open ? okay i have already apply some changes and it's running on codepen too. here is link :
https://codepen.io/bhautik1206/pen/XWLNoQB

What's the point of CDNs if I have to manually copy all the code myself?
